# How to perform a breakpoint analysis on these two variables (Survey Score and Total # of Outages)?

Tags: correlation, scatterplot, change-point, kendall-tau

Here is a snippet of the data:

[image]

I believe both of these are discrete variables. I want to first determine if a correlation exists. Would I utilize Kendall’s Rank Correlation? Second, I want to create a regression model for these variables. Third, I want to conduct a breakpoint analysis; I believe I could do so using the segmented package.

Here is a scatter plot, with jitter:

[image]

Comment: Which variable is to be the response variable?  What is the meaning of `job.id`?  Why do you believe a breakpoint analysis is needed?

Comment: @whuber, I am interested in seeing how many outages the survey score tends to drop. Is it 2 outages? etc. That is the main question I want to solve. The response variable would be total,outages (total_erts_given in the scatter plot). Job.id is just the ID of each order.